# How exactly do I go about picking locks?

Tags: divine-divinity

I've chosen to play a Survivor in *Divine Divinity*. I noticed that one of the starting skills was "Lockpick" which I've always found useful to have from the start.

The problem is, I don't actually know *how* to pick a lock! I've selected the skill while standing next to the locked item, I've selected the skill and then selected the locked item, and a myriad of other attempts. So far, nothing has worked.

**How do I pick those pesky locks?**

Comment: Maybe you need a lockpick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To be able to use the lock pick skill you need to have lock picks in
>   your inventory. To obtain lock picks you will have to explore the
>   world, or trade with merchants. If you have a lock pick in your
>   inventory, make the lock pick skill your active skill, and then
>   right-click. Your mouse cursor will change into a rotating key. Now
>   select the door or container you wish to lock pick, and if your lock
>   pick skills are good enough, the door or container will be opened when
>   you left-click on it. Each lock pick attempt will remove a lock pick
>   from your inventory. To cancel the lock picking, right-click.

[SOURCE](http://www.gamebanshee.com/divinedivinity/skills/pathofthethief.php)